# Swift: adding a button programmatically without supplying a frame during initialization

Tags: swift, uiview, constraints

Suppose I want to add a `UIBUtton` programmatically. Every `UIView` constructor requires a `CGFrame`, but in my case I want the size to be intrinsic and the location to be anchored to the super view's center.

- If I instantiate the `UIBUtton` element without supplying a frame, I see it in the debug view hierarchy but not on the screen.
- If I supply a frame, I basically guess the size and the `x,y` values brake the constraint I later add.

What is the proper way to add a button programmatically?

Thanks!

EDIT: There's no problem instantiating without a `CGFrame`. I didn't see the button because I didn't add

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

which is done automatically by the interface builder.

Comment: `let button = UIButton()`, `view.addSubview(button)`, than add constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using auto layout, set `translateAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` and ignore the frame, but don't forget to add constraints manually.

Here is a simple example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // no auto layout
    let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    view.addSubview(v)
    // with auto layout
    let v2 = UIView()
    v2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    // use auto layout
    v2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // add width / height constraints
    v2.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: v2, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100))
    v2.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: v2, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100))
    // must add to hirarchy before adding the following constraints
    view.addSubview(v2)
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: v2, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 100))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: v2, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    // auto layout, visual format
    let v3 = UIView()
    v3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v3.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    let views = [ "v3" : v3 ]
    // must add v3 as subview before adding constraints referencing the parent view
    view.addSubview(v3)
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-200-[v3(100)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[v3(100)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
}
```

For many views, there's no need to specify size as some views provide the size they want with `intrinsicContentSize`.
You can use that for buttons to make them take the size they 'need', or force another size using constraints.
For custom views - you may override this property to provide your own 'needed size' logic.